# В каких случаях можно вычитать указатели в Си?

Tags: c, строки, указатели

Конструкция

```
char *c = "aaa"+"bbb";
```

Запрещена, хотя это и не совсем очевидно. Ведь сложение двух строк все равно что суммирование двух указателей, т.е. суммирование **адресов**. Какие трудности это вызывает у компилятора? Ему может не понравиться, что данная инструкция вылезает за допустимые пределы?
А, тогда, почему можно вычитать указатели? Где есть об этом полная информация?

Comment: Видимо так: `char *c = "aaa" "bbb";` Остальное про вычитание неясно... Что хочется получить в результате.

Comment: При чем здесь "трудности компилятора"? Операция сложения адресов бессмыслена в контексте языка высокого уровня - получается бессмысленный адрес. Вот ее и нет. Операция вычитания указателей определена только для элементов одного массива и смысл ее вполне естественен - получается расстояние в элементах. Поэтому она есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Про вычитание указателей:**

> #### C11: 6.5.6 Additive operators
>
> ...
>
> 7 For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an
>   array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the
>   type of the object as its element type.
>
> ...
>
> 9 When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object,
>   or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the
>   subscripts of the two array elements. ...

То есть чтобы два указателя можно было вычесть, они должны показывать на элементы одного массива. (Либо на несуществующий элемент сразу после конца этого массива.)

Также, если указатель указывает на переменную, которая не лежит в массиве, то считается, что он указывает на нулевой элемент массива длинной 1. (Иначе результат `&a - &a == 0` был бы не определен.)

Если условие выполнено, тогда `a[x] - a[y] == x - y`.

---

**Про сложение указателей:**

Как в комментариях уже написали, это просто не имеет смысла.

> сложение двух строк все равно что суммирование двух указателей

Это не так. Чтобы сложить две строки, нужно либо дописать в конец одной строки другую, либо выделить новый кусок памяти и скопировать туда обе строки. В первом случае адрес не изменится, а во втором - никак не будет зависеть от адресов этих двух строк.

Или вот вам жизненный пример:

> Вася живет на ул. А, дом 17.
>   Петя живет на ул. А, дом 19.
>
> `19-17 = 2`, значит Васе нужно пройти 2 дома, чтобы добраться до Пети. Так 
>   как число положительное, идти нужно в направлении увеличения номеров.
>
> `17-19 = -2`, значит Пете нужно пройти 2 дома, чтобы добраться до Васи. Так 
>   как число отрицательное, идти нужно в направлении уменьшения номеров.
>
> `17+19 = 36`, но это число не имеет какого-то особого значения. Даже дома с таким номером может не существовать.